# (ruby) ruby sockets: how to create a POST request?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sockets, post

How does one create a POST request using TCPSocket in Ruby? Is there a special format to making a post? I have the following but I get a parse error (it's for a rails server):

```
require 'socket'

s = TCPSocket.open("localhost", 3000)
s.puts("POST /<controller>/<action> HTTP/1.1")
s.puts("Host: localhost:3000")
s.puts("Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
s.puts("Content-Length: 103\r\n\r\n")
```

Comment: Looks ok at first blush. I assume that <controller> and <action> are placeholders and you are really posting the proper values... Are you then actually following up with 103 bytes of data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Host:` field should **not** include the port number.

Answer (score 1):

Found [this article](http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/92504) that may be of some use to you. I especially like Eric Hodel's comment about how to do it with Net::HTTP. I know you specified that you wanted to do TCPSocket.send (presumably because you're working on something slightly more interesting than just sending POSTs), but if you aren't doing something more complicated you may be able to use Net::HTTP and rejoice at how easy it is.